# gpg: decryption failed: No secret key without first encrypting/decrypting a file

Tags: gnupg

Okay, this is a very strange case of this "No secret key" error.  I've looked at all the other answers related to this and none of them are related to my problem.

On my machine I do this..

```sh
gpg --export-secret-keys me@example.com
```

On a new WSL 2 Linux machine I do this...

```sh
gpg --import /tmp/keys.asc
echo 'enter 5 for trust level'
gpg --edit-key me@example.com trust
# I enter '5' trust level and exit
```

Now I should be ready for my encrypted backup restore, but it fails...

```sh
# ssh mount my backup on my NAS to /media/backup
sshfs tdanas:/backup /media/backup/
cat /media/backup/cloud-tar/2021/05/home.0.backupaa | gpg -d | ( cd /; tar -g /dev/null -xvz)
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 465E18C472F84F14, created 2011-01-05
      "User Name <me@example.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

If I do the following (decrypt a file and not a stream), it prompts for my password on decryption, and the problem completely vanishes.

```sh
gpg -d /media/backup/cloud-tar/2021/05/home.0.backupaa | ( cd /; tar -g /dev/null -xvz)
```

```sh
gpg --list-secret-keys
sec   rsa2048 2011-01-05 [SC]
      5ABF9709EFF6255C3B9DC4D9F029102596EDB6DB
uid           [ultimate] User Name <me@example.com>
ssb   rsa2048 2011-01-05 [E]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, lol.  the stdin is already consumed, so it can't prompt for a password at that point, unless I used a gui password prompt